# Changing contents of JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Let's try this one:

```
JTree tree = new JTree (DefaultMutableTreeNode ("blank"));
```

for the program has only started.  After the user selects a data file, it's read into memory and a new tree is created:

```
tree = new JTree (dataobject.makeTree (file.getName ()));
```

However, the frame which holds the JTree still just shows 'blank' and a tree that's empty besides the root.

How does one totally destroy the old tree and assign a new one?  I presume reassignment should work, with garbage collection catching the old data.  However, clearly my presumption is wrong.

Comment: Don't create a new `JTree`, instead, create a new `TreeModel` and apply it to the tree which is already on the screen.  This is the bases of the MVC paradigm, where the view and the data are separated

Comment: *"How does one totally destroy the old tree and assign a new one? I presume reassignment should work, with garbage collection catching the old data. However, clearly my presumption is wrong."* - Assigning a new value to a variable doesn't "destroy" the old data previously held by it, it just makes it point to the new variable.  Every thing else is still pointing to the old data (for example, the container which is showing the tree).

Comment: JTree, DefaultMutableTreeNode, and now something else called TreeModel?  They don't make this easy.

Thanks, I'll investigate.

Comment: See [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) for more details.  MVC is used extensively through out Swing (and JavaFX and the Web and ios and Android and ... you get the idea).  Have a look at [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) for more details.  In fact, using `JTree#setModel` is a lot simpler to having to remove the old `JTree` and and a new one and then revalidate and the UI to make sure it's all layout nicely :P

Comment: Wow, again, thanks.  This MVC model hasn't been brought up in any of my classes so far but it looks like a basic concept to discuss.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to mark this as answered but I successfully implemented what I've learned from this exchange and further research.  Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to share what you've learned as your own answer ;)